# lucene and ontology

Tags: lucene, ontology

I do not have much experience with Lucene, but I need to finish a research.
I want to use Lucene indexing based on ontology. So, I need any kind of advice, what should I use, how to combine Lucene with ontology domain and things like that.

Thanks,

- Lucky

Comment: You're going to need at lot more detail on what you're looking for

Comment: It should be simple. I already have an ontology, and I want to index documents based on that ontology, but using Lucene. This ontology has tiples <name;author;book>. I want for each triple to create document which contains fields name, author and book.

Comment: It sounds like you know exactly what you want to do, check out [Lucene Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) to quickly get started with Lucene

Comment: Here are details... I know about Lucene Solr, but I didn't try working with Solr. I have manually annotated document. Now I want to annotate the same repository using my annotator, but based on the same ontology. If I can extend Solr with mu ontology, than that is the solution... Sorry if I ask a stupid question, I'm still new :)

Comment: It's probably a combination of me not understanding the definition of some of these words and what you're looking for. Can you edit your question with a example of what you have, and what you want to get to?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try... Maybe we should be clear about few things. As I understand, Lucene Solr is platform for indexing and searching documents? I want to index content based on my domain ontology, which has already defined concepts. Like KIM platform - KIM platform uses Proton Ontology.

Answer (score 0):

In Lucene, you might do something like

```
protected Document createDocumentFromTuple(Tuple t) {
    Document doc = new Document(); // this is the Lucene document to create
    String docid = createId(t);
    doc.add(new Field("id", docid, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED );
    doc.add(new Field("name", t.getName(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED );
    doc.add(new Field("author", t.getAuthor(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED );
    doc.add(new Field("book", t.getBook(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED );
    return doc;
}
```

This assumes that the three fields should not be decomposed into constituent terms by some Analyzer; if that's not a correct assumption, change the last parameter to `Field.Index.ANALYZED`.

The Solr equivalent (which might make more sense if you are not analyzing the fields, would be

```
protected SolrInputDocument createIndexableDocument(Tuple t) {
    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    String docid = createId(t);
    doc.addField("id", docid);
    doc.addField("name", t.getName());
    doc.addField("author", t.getAuthor());
    doc.addField("book", t.getBook());
    return doc;
}
```

In Solr, the server-side configuration determines which fields are stored, how they are parsed, etc.

In each case, you will need to figure out how to create a unique id for each Tuple. One way to do it is to generate a hash of the concatenation (with delimiters) of the three values.

Comment: OK, thank you! I will try this, and I think that this will work. I've tried to use Nutch, I saw that I can use any ontology I like, with Nutch of course. But, I think that this will do the job.
Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if this does what you want.

Comment: OK, I will. Maybe I’m boring with this ontology stuff… but is there a way to transform ontology to tuple, or set of tuples? Or, is it a better idea, to extract certain tuple from ontology?

Comment: This sounds like a different question & you will need to make it much clearer what you mean by ontology, what your tuple store is, what it means to extract a tuple from an ontology. The more focused you make your question, the more likely you are to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Actually, I was just thinking about ontology because that was the idea. But things are little bit different now. The thing is that I don’t have OWL file, in meantime I got mdb file. This file has few tables (Keyword, Metadata, MetadataAuthor…). So, tuples are even better in this case. I’ll have to choose from which fields I’ll create tuple, and this example that you gave me, will do the work. Thank you for comments.